# Why does the Java version starts with 1?

Tags: java

Why does the command (on the Windows command-line) `java -version` return **Java version "1.7.0"** and not **Java version 7.0**? What does **1** mean?

Comment: it is actual version of java, just like 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 1.7 and so on.

Comment: I understand that the version is the next part of the '1', but I don't understand why uses the '1' because it causes confusion by thinking that the version is java 1.7 not java 7 in stric terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Java 1.2 came out Sun decided to market it as "Java 2", presumably to differentiate from Microsoft, as the lawsuit was still on at the time. They've followed suit ever since, so 1.7 is now "Java 7".

Answer (score 0):

It means that this is the seventh major release of java, but the version number is 1.7. Version numbers don't have to increment in integral units for major releases.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is actual Java version. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history